# Howto query TFS 2013 API for git repositories in a TeamProjectCollection?

Tags: git

Does anybody know how to get all git repositories within an TFS 2013 TeamProjectCollection?
Documentation is very poor for git related stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client?

Some pseudo code

```
GitHttpClient client = new GitHttpClient("collectionurl", creds)
var gitRepos = client.GetRepositoriesAsync().Result
```

Comment: The GitHttpClient resides in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.dll which is only present in the GAC? (VS2013 is installed). Does no reference assembly exist?

Comment: All TFS SDK dlls are present in the GAC itself which can be referenced from your project but packaging will be your responsibility (including rights to do so)

Answer (score 1):

The Web API's are apparently the correct (and better documented) approach.  e.g.

```
GET http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_apis/git/repositories
```

See: http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-git-repositories-vsi