# Can't find GitHttpClient class in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, git, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I need to get a list of repositories belonging to a TFS 2013 Team Project, but I cannot find the method to do it.

As directed by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173687/howto-query-tfs-2013-api-for-git-repositories-in-a-teamprojectcollection), I started looking for the GitHttpClient class.

Sure enough, it is documented in two separate locations:

[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.GitHttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclient.aspx)

[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client.GitHttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.git.client.githttpclient.aspx)

However, I can find neither of these assemblies on my system.

Developing in VS 2013 on Windows 7, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are private TFS server classes.  Not only are they *not* available in Visual Studio, they are *not* public classes, or expected to be used by consumers.

This information is available in Visual Studio Online (and subsequently will be available in newer TFS on-premises installations) via the REST APIs:  http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-overview-vsi

There is a C# API that wraps the REST API - [Infinity.Net](https://github.com/ethomson/infinity.net) (https://github.com/ethomson/infinity.net), which I hope proves a helpful surface for .NET development.  Though it's woefully incomplete (lacking Work Item Tracking, Builds, etc), it *is* complete for the Git functionality.